# Monitoring for the transfer job is not showing error count even though there have been errors

Tags: google-cloud-platform, logging, error-handling, monitoring

I have a transfer service that has failed and shows an error. When going to monitoring,within the console, there says there are no data available. I have errors in my transfer job but monitoring does not show the errors.
Please help

Ive turned on google monitoring API and all other metrics show up but the error count doenst